Excessive Build Time for LTO vmlinux.o in Android GKI Build Process
Since the implementation of GKI (Generic Kernel Image) in Android 12 and later versions, I've been experiencing excessively long build times for the LTO vmlinux.o step when building the kernel modules for use in Android. During this step, CPU usage remains around 1% and it takes over 30 minutes. Is there a way to reduce this build time?
Normal Time Required for Android Kernel Build
